# Duplicate UITextField's being added when tableView scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm encountering an issue where duplicate UITextField's are being added when the cells are re-used, which isn't what I want to happen. I recall encountering a similar issue previously, but for the life of me cannot remember what I did to solve it.

It's no doubt something obvious, but I can't seem to find anything helpful. I've tried encasing the if/else statements in an 'if (cell == null)' as some people have been suggested, but this just results in a blank table being formed.

Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (indexPath.section == 0){

            productField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
            [productField setPlaceholder:@"Product"];
            if ([productData length] > 0){
                [productField setText:productData];
                [productField setEnabled:false];
            }
            [cell addSubview:productField];

        } else if (indexPath.section == 1){

            issueField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
            [issueField setPlaceholder:@"What's the issue?"];
            [issueField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            [cell addSubview:issueField];

        } else if (indexPath.section == 2){

            emailField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
            [emailField setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
            [emailField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            [emailField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
            [emailField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
            [cell addSubview:emailField];

        } else if (indexPath.section == 3){

            notesField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
            [notesField setPlaceholder:@"Any notes to add?"];
            [notesField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            [cell addSubview:notesField];

        } else if (indexPath.section == 4){

            sendFeedback = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
            [sendFeedback setTitle:@"Send Feedback" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sendFeedback setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(111/255.0f) green:(31/255.0f) blue:(68/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
            [sendFeedback.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MaryAnn" size:20.0]];
            [sendFeedback addTarget:self action:@selector(sendFeedback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [cell addSubview:sendFeedback];

        }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you should use static cell in place of dequeueReusableCell them.

Comment: Can't you create custom cell?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I opted for static cells (completely forgot about them) as it's something that'll only be used in the test versions, and not in the production version of the application.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is reusable cells in table view, try this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        textField.tag=101;
        [cell addSubview:textField];

        UIButton *sendFeedback = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        sendFeedback.tag=102;
        [sendFeedback setTitle:@"Send Feedback" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sendFeedback setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(111/255.0f) green:(31/255.0f) blue:(68/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
        [sendFeedback.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MaryAnn" size:20.0]];
        [sendFeedback addTarget:self action:@selector(sendFeedback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell addSubview:sendFeedback];

    }
    UITextField* textField=(UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UIButton *sendFeedback = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    sendFeedback.hidden=YES;
    textField.hidden=NO;
     [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Product"];
        if ([productData length] > 0)
        {
            [textField setText:productData];
            [textField setEnabled:false];
        }

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){

        [textField setPlaceholder:@"What's the issue?"];
        [textField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 2){

        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
        [textField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [textField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
        [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 3){

        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Any notes to add?"];
        [textField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 4)
    {
        textField.hidden=YES;
        sendFeedback.hidden=NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

// You not directly access textField.text in table view,you assign textField.text using global variable or dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you keep adding the subviews to the cells. For example you add the `productField` to the cell at index 0. When that cell is reused, you add another subview to it, but the `productField` would still be there. A possible solution would be to remove the subview before adding a new one. Your `if` statements would be something like this:

```
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        // Remove the old subview
        UIView *oldSubview = [cell viewWithTag:5];
        [oldSubview removeFromSuperview];

        productField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [productField setPlaceholder:@"Product"];
        if ([productData length] > 0){
            [productField setText:productData];
            [productField setEnabled:false];
        }
        // Set a tag for the new subview, so you can remove it later
        productField.tag = 5;
        [cell addSubview:productField];
    }
```

Use the same `tag` in every `if` statement.

**Edit:**

Or you can just do it like @pawan suggested and use static cells.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since you're recycling cells (and you should), you are reusing non empty cells and add new controls on top of it.

The usual way to handle that is to build your custom UITableViewCell subclass, and have the various textfields and other UI controls as properties.
Then you can show/hide those UI controls in each section

It would look something like that:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            productField.hidden=NO;
            issueField.hidden=YES;

        } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            productField.hidden=YES;
            issueField.hidden=NO;
        }
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not after you instantiate the cell, you remove all of the subviews from the cells contentView

```
for( UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews )
    [view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.section];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {

        productField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [productField setPlaceholder:@"Product"];
        if ([productData length] > 0){
            [productField setText:productData];
            [productField setEnabled:false];
        }
        [cell addSubview:productField];

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        issueField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [issueField setPlaceholder:@"What's the issue?"];
        [issueField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [cell addSubview:issueField];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 2){

        emailField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [emailField setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
        [emailField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [emailField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
        [emailField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
        [cell addSubview:emailField];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 3){

        notesField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [notesField setPlaceholder:@"Any notes to add?"];
        [notesField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [cell addSubview:notesField];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 4){

        sendFeedback = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 45)];
        [sendFeedback setTitle:@"Send Feedback" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sendFeedback setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(111/255.0f) green:(31/255.0f) blue:(68/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
        [sendFeedback.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MaryAnn" size:20.0]];
        [sendFeedback addTarget:self action:@selector(sendFeedback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell addSubview:sendFeedback];

    }

    }
    return cell;
}
```